# Super slim library not support header with multiple textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using superslim library for sticky header view but when i use other layouts like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout in header_item.xml it will not sticky.

But when i use single textview in header_item.xml it will work properly but i don't wonn't that.

header_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_user_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/lightgrey"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layoutDirection="locale"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textDirection="locale"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:slm_headerDisplay="sticky|inline"
                app:slm_isHeader="true"
                app:slm_section_headerMarginStart="56dip"
                tools:text="Header Item" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What i need to change for sticky header with multiple view.Please help me out. I am not alter the coding of superslim library just try to add multipleview on header. but it will stay sticky when i add multiple view on it.

Comment: can you post link of using lib and post some of code you have tried.

Comment: https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM, i am just add view on header_item.xml, nothing else

Comment: have problem with add layout in header item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add layout in **header.xml** in as like below code. This method work for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:slm_headerDisplay="inline|sticky"
           app:slm_isHeader="true"
           app:slm_section_headerMarginStart="56dip">

    <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="start"
           android:padding="16dip"
           android:layoutDirection="locale"
           android:textDirection="locale"
           android:textSize="24sp"
           tools:text="Header Item" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_user_id"
            android:text="A"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```